# Meaning of しみじみ in this context

Tags: translation, meaning

I am currently trying to translate the interview from this clip -> https://clyp.it/0ywgfz3q

My transcription and translation attempt were

> このHaikyuuの中で出会えた人たちっていうのは = People who met in Haikyuu
>
> 今後の、ま、付き合っていく中でも = are people who I will keep company with from now on.
>
> ずーっと、あの、一緒に遊んだりとか、こう、ご飯行ったりとか、= We always hang out and go for a meal together
>
> そういうことが出来る本当に大切な仲に僕はなれたと思っているので = Being able to do such things is very important to me (I'm not so sure about this translation)
>
> 心から、なんか、**しみじみ**とそういうふうに思うことが出来ますね。> ??????

I got stuck at the last bit cause I'm not sure about **しみじみ**.

After some research, it has different meanings based on this website https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/100815/meaning/m0u/

But I'm not sure, which one exactly did he mean here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The しみじみ here is used in the sense of definition #1 in that dictionary ("to think or feel something deeply or keenly"), as the other poster has said.

---

It seems that you're not parsing the sentence correctly, I'm afraid.

> このHaikyuuの中で出会えた人たちっていうのは

As for / Speaking of the people whom I met in Haikyuu,

> 今後の、ま、付き合っていく中でも

when / while I keep company with them from now on / in the future as well,

> ずーっと、あの、一緒に遊んだりとか、こう、ご飯行ったりとか、そういうことができる（← modifies 仲）

(... friendship where) we'll always be able to continue doing things like, hanging out, or eating out together

> 本当に大切な仲に僕はなれたと思っているので

I think that I could build/develop a truly important relationship/friendship with them (where we'll be able to continue...), so

> 心から、なんか、しみじみとそういうふうに思うことが出来ますね。

I can think/feel that way deeply/keenly from the bottom of my heart.

Putting them all together:

> "With the people I met in Haikyuu, I think I have built/developed a truly important friendship, where, while I keep company with them from now on / in the future, we'll always be able to continue doing things like hanging out or eating out together, so I can feel that way deeply/keenly from the bottom of my heart."

Comment: I was wondering which part indicates **while** from "while I keep company with them from now on / in the future"? +_+ My apologies I tend to make a mistake, when it comes to long sentences T_T

Comment: @Maru I think the 「今後～～V+中でも」 is like "when / while I do ~~ in the future as well (as before)." 「V+[中]{なか}で」 can mean "while/when doing~~."

Comment: I was wondering if you consider these as 丁寧語？

Comment: @Maru Which part? 今後 and 中で aren't.

Comment: @Maru They are not really 丁寧語 (polite language), but I think 今後 and ～するなかで are less casual and a little more literary than これから and ～しながら/～するとき, respectively.

Comment: @broccoliforest I see I thought the whole context is 丁寧語 since it is relatively different from how I heard from Anime. (I just switched from watching anime to listening to these interviews to practice my listening skills, which I believe is still at a poor level OTL)